# How can I trigger sound on killing enemy?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to trigger a sound when the player kills an enemy, as you can see in the code below. While colliding with an enemy causes it to be destroyed and raises the kill count successfully, it does not produce the desired sound. A similar script does manage to trigger a sound when the player jumps, so I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class CollectibleItem : MonoBehaviour {
[SerializeField] private string itemName;
[SerializeField] private int pointsValue;
[SerializeField] private AudioSource soundSource;
[SerializeField] private AudioClip killSound;

ScoreBoard board;

void Start() {
    var uiObject = GameObject.Find("Timer");
    ScoreBoard board = uiObject.GetComponent<ScoreBoard>();
}

void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other) {
    soundSource.PlayOneShot(killSound);
    Managers.Inventory.AddItem(itemName);
    Destroy(this.gameObject);
}
}
```

Comment: Just a guess but maybe it doesn't have time to play before you Destroy the game object? What if you comment out `Destroy`?

Comment: That was it. Thank you, Crowcoder!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that there is no reference to the `AudioSource` component.
I assume your AudioSource is attached to the same GameObject as this script. Just add the following to your `Start` method.

```
soundSource=GetComponent<AudioSource>();
```

I'm also a bit sceptical about your `AudioClip`.

Comment: I think `[SerializeField] private xxx` makes the variables visible inside the editor.

Comment: You can always see what's going on if you switch the inspector to debug mode. I don't have a Unity installation at hand, but I'm pretty sure you can assign SerializeField members in the editor: https://forum.unity.com/threads/reason-s-to-serializefield-a-private-variable.513806/

Comment: I just realised that too. I must have been thinking about a built game. That code wouldn't work in production, would it? And yes, you are right.

Comment: What code? All of it would work in production (the fields are serialized after all) and there's no editor in production, so no inspector to worry about. Or are you referring to something else?

Comment: I think you are right. Thank you for the correction.